# Is this a place to ask blockchain questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic-definition

I don't have a specific question, but I can see the possibility of future questions about blockchain development. I believe there are enough questions that could and will be asked about blockchain development.

However, there is no blockchain tag. The closest tags have to do with distributed computing or distributed systems.

So I am here to suggest that there is a blockchain tag added since I do not have reputation to do it myself.

Comment: Have you tried https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about blockchain technology are not likely to be on topic. As an analogy, blockchains are as on topic as SQL databases.

The point is, this site is about software engineering. That means: process-level questions and design-level questions. And to some degree, the community accepts questions about basic software development concepts.

So a design level problem that involves a blockchain would be OK because its just another kind of database. If the question would still be on topic if you replace “blockchain” with “distributed database” you're likely good to go. In particular, questions about data modelling are a good fit for this site. But note that implementation-level questions about using a specific technology are off topic.

You should also consider what kind of experts are on the site. Here, we have experts about software engineering, but not experts about blockchains. Specifically, questions about the technical minutiae of blockchains or questions about implementing your own blockchain are off topic, and likely also too broad. Even when these questions are not closed, you are unlikely to receive an useful answer.

If your question is about using some blockchain-related library, it belongs on Stack Overflow.
If you have a mathematical question about cryptographic techniques, consider looking at the Cryptography site.
The Bitcoin site is about cryptocurrencies and related technologies which may or may not include your questions.
In any case, read their help centers carefully before asking.

A blockchain tag might be added once there are on-topic questions that are helpfully described by that tag. Adding a tag in advance is not possible, because tags without questions will be automatically deleted by the system.